# connecting sqlite to C program

Tags: c, sqlite

**[SOLVED]**
All I had to do was open the `sqlite3.c` file inside my "project tree" [like this](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Creating_a_new_project#Changing_file_composition) and include `sqlite3.h` in the header.

I'm trying to connect my C program (using Code Blocks) to a database. I've already downloaded all the key files from the [sqlite website](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/) like *amalgamation* zip file that comes with `shell.c`, `sqlite3.c`, `sqlite3.h`, and `sqlite3ext.h`.

I found this [this tutorial](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/) on how to use libraries on code blocks. It's pretty simple, but then I realized that none of the files that came with *amalgamation* zip were `.lib` or `.a`. I know sqlite uses libraries, but all the files I listed above are source code files that access those libraries by themselves.

[How to compile sqlite](https://sqlite.org/howtocompile.html) -> On their web site they have some good info: *Everything is contained within a single code file, so it is easy to drop into the source tree of a larger C or C++ program.*  They meant the `sqlite3.c` file. But what did they mean by "dropping into the source tree"?

On the same page, there is a section *Compiling The Command-Line Interface*. I kind of got it the main points... I also found a `sqlite shell` [tutorial here](https://sqlite.org/cli.html), so I downloaded the shell and now I can create/modify DBs. Although I feel like I'm pretty close to getting it to work on my C program, I still can't implement any DB from the source files or shell into my code.
Any thoughts?

```
#include <stdio.h>      // printf
#include <sqlite3.h>    // SQLite header (from /usr/include)

int main()
{
    sqlite3 *db;        // database connection
    int rc;             // return code
    char *errmsg;       // pointer to an error string

    /*
     * open SQLite database file test.db
     * use ":memory:" to use an in-memory database
     */
    rc = sqlite3_open(":memory:", &db);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        printf("ERROR opening SQLite DB in memory: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        goto out;
    }
    printf("opened SQLite handle successfully.\n");

    /* use the database... */

out:
    /*
     * close SQLite database
     */
    sqlite3_close(db);
    printf("database closed.\n");
}
```

Also, on the [Command Line Shell For SQLite](https://sqlite.org/cli.html)  you can find a detailed explanation on how to transfer existing data (created from outside the C program since I still can't connect the DB to my C program) to a .txt file. This is good to know and all, but not exactly what I want. I could make it work using a lot of `fread`, `fprintf`etc...but that's not quite as good as having a actual DB implemented into your program. For instance, if later I wanted to make my `program.c` into a `program.exe` I could do it with the DB embedded inside the `program.exe`.

Comment: Please show the compilation errors as well.

Comment: This include line, `#include "sqlite3.c"`, seems like a bad idea, and probably not what you want. Start with removing that include and see whether you get the same, or less, compilation errors.

Comment: @9769953 I did. I took a screenshot of the compilation error: _undefined reference to sqlite3_versison_, it's linked in the question. I know it looks weird, I first wrote `#include <sqlite3.c>` as usual, but this way I couldn't even run the program...the compilation stopped exactly at the `#include <sqlite3.c>`. That's why I changed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm getting the compilation error when using `#include <sqlite3.c>`, which must be the correct way, because I couldn't get the  sqlite/code blocks configuration correctly.

Comment: From your comments, it's unclear to me whether you are (still) including or not sqlite3.c.

Comment: Don't link to images; don't use images containing code or errors etc. Copy-paste the errors (format as code block) into your question.

Comment: Do you know how to link to a library? And compile code that then has to link to a library?

Comment: I did it. I don't think so, is it like when you use the standard libraries at the beginning of the program?

Comment: Your last error, which includes "ld returned 1 exit status", is a *linker* error. The compilation succeeded, but not the linking stage. You have to *link* with the sqlite library. That would usually be with the use of an `-l` option, but I don't know how one configures that in Code::Blocks. The actual question you thus want to ask is "how do I link to the sqlite library in Code::Blocks"?

Comment: That's one of the things I didn't get it. I just added a link that I found explaining how to connect libraries using code blocks, but when I was following the steps I realized that I could only select .lib files and I don't have any...only source files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amalgation expects that you put all files of the amalgation in you project folder, that you add `#include "sqlite3.h"` in your sources that want to access sqlite and that you make sqlite3.c a member of your project.

Assuming a gcc command line compiler, you should do:

```
gcc main.c sqlite3.c -lpthread -o foo
```

No need for a library here, and never try to include `sqlite3.c`.

Comment: All amalgation files are inside the project's folder. What do you mean by make sqlite3.c a member of my project? Like coding wise? I did that too.    And how do I open the gcc command line? Or is through the command prompt?